# Check Box Categorization

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I am creating a sign-up program on my website for my service club. What I want to do is have a person type their name and contact information into some text boxes and then check off check boxes where each box corresponds to an event that is happening that week.

The challenge that I am have is putting everyone in different HTML tables to display who is going to what event. In addition, some people may sign-up for more than one event so I do not know how to have their name inputted into multiple tables individual for each event.

I will try make what I am trying to say a little simpler by an example:

Jane is a member of this club and wants to sign up for the events for this week. She first types her name and contact information into the first two text boxes. Then she has three options for events this week: "event1," "event 2," and "event3." She sees that she can go to "event1" and "event3" so she checks the two boxes and submits. I want to be able to put her name and contact information into two separate tables designated for "event1" and "event3." I want to be able to see the exact information in "event1" than I see in the "event3" table.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: so what is your question? what effort have you made?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have finished all the coding for the form, the database processing, and the Html table for displaying the list of people who sign up for each event

Comment: The problem for me is categorization using check box options.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a query question, this isn't exact due to the lack of supplied code i cant do that but this is the basic idea.

```
// timestamp for 7 days ahead. change 7 to the number of days.
$timestamp = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

$sql = "SELECT eventid, eventname, eventdate FROM events 
    WHERE eventdate > NOW() 
        AND eventdate < (NOW() + $timestamp)
    ORDER BY eventdate ASC";
    // ASC or DESC as needed
```

You can make that fit your needs just by changing columns and table name to suit.

Comment: So can I have a person be added to the event "here" and "there" on two different tables?